# Why I need to convert DataRow again into DataRow?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, datatable

Look into following code block,

```
DataTable _table = new DataTable();

//1) Why I need to Convert DataRow again into DataRow by Casting ?
List<DataRow> _rows = _table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(a => a).ToList();

//2) Why this is not valid?
List<DataRow> _rows = _table.Rows.Select(a => a).ToList();
```

In first case why I need to convert DataRow again into DataRow? and Why second case not valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataTable.Rows`'s return type, the `DataRowCollection` class, dates from the old, dark times before generics, and, thus, only implements `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

You can use the shiny new [`DataTable.AsEnumerable` LINQ extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, which returns an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`:

```
List<DataRow> _rows = _table.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a).ToList();
```

In fact, you do not need `Select(a => a)` at all:

```
List<DataRow> _rows = _table.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

---

PS: There is a [Microsoft Connect feature request](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/470088/datarowcollection-should-implement-ienumerable-datarow) to make `DataRowCollection` implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. However, since an easy alternative is available (`AsEnumerable`), they probably have other priorities.